# EmberJS computed.sort - sorting by associated model property

Tags: sorting, ember.js, computed-properties

I have a simple `belongsTo` model relationship:

contract.js:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    object               : DS.belongsTo('object'),
    ....
})
```

object.js:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    street              : DS.attr('string'),
    zip                 : DS.attr('string'),
    city                : DS.attr('string'),
    ...
})
```

In my controller for an entity that holds many `contracts`, I'd like to sort by the street name of the associated `object`, but somehow this

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({

    sortOrder: ['object.street'],
    sortedObjects: Ember.computed.sort('model.contracts', 'sortOrder')

    ...
});
```

doesn't work.

Using a custom comparator function a la

```
function(a, b){
    if (a.street > b.street) {
      return 1;
    } else if (a.street < b.street) {
      return -1;
    }
}
```

I found out that `a` and `b` are `Promises`, but somehow I don't see how to get them sorted via a nested attribute (the object's street)

### Edit

To clarify the code a little more:

```
contracts : Ember.computed.alias('model.contracts'),
street: Ember.computed.alias('realty.street'),

sortOrder: ['realty.street'],
sortedOwnedRealties: Ember.computed.sort('contracts.@each.street', function (a, b) {
    console.log(Ember.get(a, 'id'));
    console.log(Ember.get(a, 'street'));

    //return 1;
})
```

That function prints `undefined` to the console for the `street`, but the correct `id`.

I've renamed `object` to `realty` for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are probably `PromiseObject`s, which are both, `Ember.Object` and `Promise`. There are a few things you do that might be not a good idea:

First `object` is a reserved keyword. It's not a good idea to have a model or relationship named `object`, even if it might work.

Second your computed property has the wrong dependency key. Actually you would want something like `'modelcontracts.@each.object.street'` instead of `'modelcontracts'`, however this will *not* work because `'@each.a.b'` is not supported. The solution is to create an alias to the street on the contract:

```
street: Ember.computed.alias('object.street'),
```

And then you can use this as your dependency key: `modelcontracts.@each.street`.

Next in your custom comparator function you access `a.street` by dot notation. This will not work and is unreliable for ember objects. Always use `.get()` to access the properties:

```
import Ember form 'ember';
const {get} = Ember;


function(a, b){
  if(get(a, 'street') > get(b, 'street')) {...}
}
```

However also notice that without the `computed.alias` I've mentioned above it's not `get(a, 'street')` but `get(a, 'object.street')`.

---

The problem why your code is not working is probably that `object` is loaded async, and so at the time your CP is evaluated the street is not yet loaded. Adding the correct dependency key will probably fix this.

Comment: Apologies, the `object` property was the result of me simplifying the code too eagerly. Of course, it is not called `object`. And I had another typo in `model.contracts`. I feel I'm getting closer, but not quite there - please see the edit above.

Comment: You should add the `street: Ember.computed.alias('realty.street')` to your `contract.js` next to your `realty:DS.belongsTo('realty')` and not where you have your sorting CP.

Comment: Thanks! Using the simpler version I even narrowed it down to: `sortOrder: ['street'],    sortedOwnedRealties: Ember.computed.sort('contracts', 'sortOrder')`